# How to use PHPSecLib to execute ssh command for multiple remote servers

Tags: php, linux, phpseclib

I spent hours to get this works. Currently this is a part of my code

```
<?php
function adduser($name, $server, $username, $password, $useradd, $passadd, $date){
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($server, '22'); //starting the ssh connection to localhost
if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) { //if you can't log on...
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$output = $ssh->exec('adduser '.$useradd.' --no-create-home --shell /usr/bin/tunnel_shell && echo '.$useradd.':'.$passadd.' | chpasswd');
echo $output."<br>";

}


adduser('Server 1', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'root', 'jIiVqlkV', $_POST['useradd'], $_POST['passadd'], $date);
adduser('Server 2', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'root', 'Sk9vGxbl', $_POST['useradd'], $_POST['passadd'], $date);
adduser('Server 3', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'root', 'FIsfdKzH', $_POST['useradd'], $_POST['passadd'], $date);
adduser('Server 4', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'root', '30rtUhPS', $_POST['useradd'], $_POST['passadd'], $date);

?>
```

What I am trying to do here is running multiple PHPSecLib processes to add a user to 4 of my servers at once.
**It works with 2 server but with pretty long loading.**
Then I add 2 more servers make them 4 servers in total. The script executed for minutes. At last it will show *500 internal error*. There also premature end & connection reset by peer in my log.

Is there any ways to execute add user to multiple servers at once? 
Better and faster?

Comment: If you have access to these servers, it would seem better to have the server handle the distribution of the user as opposed to the php script.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes, I own all the server. Im trying to add user to all of my server at once. Ok, let say I got 20 users to be added. It would be easier if I can add each user to the servers at once. There will be also incoming new user. It will troubling me if I need to log in to each servers to add each new user.

Comment: I think one thing that'd help is to know where the bottle neck is. If it's in the auth part of your code then installing `gmp` would probably help. If it's in the execution of the command...  do you really need the output? Maybe you could do `$ssh->read('[prompt]`)` and then `$ssh->write('adduser ...')`? That said don't immediately disconnect because if you do so in the microseconds before the command has had a chance to run it won't.

Comment: Also, if it's in the command part of your code then, at some indeterminate time in the future, https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/506#issuecomment-64956372 should help.

Comment: You could look into a piece of software called Puppet. Read http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/puppet-open-source and here
http://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/11/25/using-puppet-for-account-management/ Haven't used it myself, but my hosting provider is using it across their platform.